# Is there a way to send Data from Splunk to Salesforce?

Tags: splunk, salesforce-lightning

I need some help and guidance related to sending data from SPLUNK to Salesforce.

Basically, I am trying to extract few features and information from Splunk dashboard and I need to send that data to salesforce while creating a case. Such that the case is created with all those details automatically with the single click of the submit button from SPLUNK dashboard.

I read/tried the SPLUNK add on for Salesforce, however, this is more about pulling the salesforce data to SPLUNK but not about pushing the data from SPlUNK to salesforce.

Could you please guide me, how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Splunk Alert Actions to trigger an action against a Salesforce REST endpoint or webhook.

Refer to https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/AddonBuilder/3.0.2/UserGuide/CreateAlertActions if you wish to use the Splunk Add-On builder, or https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Alert/Configuringscriptedalerts if you are comfortable coding it yourself.

A summary of the process can be found at https://simonduff.net/splunk_alert_script/

Can you share what Salesforce API you are trying to interact with and what information you wish to provide it. It may just be as simple as creating a particular URL, rather than using REST to post information to it.

Comment: Hi @Simon, I am using python Script and using Salesforce API to insert a record i.e. I am basically creating a case in salesforce and all those data of the case will be inserted